# Rotating disk powered by a motor with torsional drag differential equation

Tags: rotational-dynamics, differential-equations

I looking for a way to solve a DE that arose from the following problem:

"An off-axis hole of radius R/2 is drilled through a disc of radius R. The mass of the remaining disc is M. The disc is then rigidly mounted on a uniform, solid, cylindrical shaft of radius R/2 and mass M.

The disc-shaft combination is mounted so that it can rotate about the shaft’s axis, which is vertical. The shaft is driven by a motor that generates constant power P. The disc-shaft combination also experiences a frictional drag torque -γω, where γ is a constant."
We can obtain the moment of inertia, I, of this body, it is equal to $ 13MR^2/12$.

We can also obtain the body's equation of motion:
$ p=Fv=Frw$
 w is the body's angular velocity, p is the power used to drive a particle at distance r from the axis.
$Fr=p/w$ Is the torque provided by the motor, in the steady state  (no resultant torque) the DE for the system is $p/w-γw=0$ and we see w tends to $\sqrt{p/γ}$. Call this steady state value $w_0$.
Now consider time taken to accelerate the disc-shaft combination from rest to angular velocity ω. there is now a resultant torque of $I\dot{w}$,
so we have to solve the following DE:

$p/w-γw=I\dot{w}$

I don't think I can integrate what comes of separating, and a trial solution of    $ w=w_oexp(-k/t)$ didn't work.

Comment: Try substituting $w(t)=\sqrt{\hat{w}(t)}$

Comment: @HaykHakobyan          Thank you, that works nicely. Why did that substitution occur to you? Does having $w^n$ in a DE suggest $W=w^n$ might be a useful substituion?

Comment: Yes, It's a general type of substitution for this type of eq-ns. You could place $w^n$ and determine the $n$ value that fits the best.